# Sound metering react-native

Tags: android, audio, react-native

Im building a react-native application.
Im trying to meter the current sound level (in decibel).

Libraries in use: [react-native-audio](https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio) and [react-native-sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound).

There is anybody familiar with this feature?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `react-native-audio` **currentMetering** value - in order to get the sound level in real-time.

First, you will have to **initialise your recorder** (which i will assume youve done). I use `prepareRecordingAtPath` in a similar way to below

```
AudioRecorder.prepareRecordingAtPath(audioPath, {
  SampleRate: 22050,
  Channels: 1,
  AudioQuality: "Low",
  AudioEncoding: "aac",
  MeteringEnabled: true
});
```

then once you've called `AudioRecorder.startRecording();` (Note you have access to `.pause()` and `.stop()` methods also

Now for handling the audio level, you are going to have to retrieve the data that is returned by the `onProgress` method. From what i remember, there should be some `currentMetering` value that you can access. Note that defining this behaviour will trigger the action every time a different decibel reading is retrieved. Like so

```
AudioRecorder.onProgress = data => {
    let decibels = Math.floor(data.currentMetering);

    //DO STUFF
  };
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: First of all - thank you.
I used `metering: true` instead of `MeteringEnabled: true.`
Be aware - that feature if for IOS only. There is an open PR for android metering suppoort in the repository..
It will work only if the `AudioRecorderManager` is up-to-date according to  this PR: https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio/pull/185/commits

Comment: @Hajaj Do you know if they have this feature for android in the public release?

Answer (score 5):

With the react-native-audio library, you can get the count for the only iOS.

For the `currentMetering` in Android, you need to customize in a native module. I have updated it add the following things in your `package.json` file instead of your code. You will get the `currentMetering` count for the Android as well as iOS.

```
"react-native-audio": "git+https://github.com/Harsh2402/react-native-audio.git",
```

Comment: Can you please share what u have changed in exiting git repo?